# Video upload size

Tags: php, nginx, ffmpeg, centos6, video-encoding

I'm having a hard time figuring this one out, so hopefully, some of you who has tried this before, will take the time to reply and share your knowledge.

I'm working on a site, which after release, will be feeded in the television and other commercial places. The site asks the user to upload a video with a story, and we expect alot of people to do so.

My problem is the whole storage/space talk. A normal, unencoded iPhone recording easily fills around 100-120 MB for a minute or two.

I've tried setting up and using FFMPEG to re-encode the movies, but the problem is, that one encoding sucks up 100% of the CPU, leaving the site inaccisible for anybody else.

Is there anything you could suggest, which would be sufficient for such a site? The client is on a budget, so price is a consideration aswell. Best of all would be a free alternative to etc. FFMPEG, but with less CPU usage.

My specs are as follows
CentOs 6 on a 
1GB ram DigitalOcean cloud service with nginx + php-fpm and mysql.

Im hoping for some cleaver folks to answer this!
Thanks in advance.
Jonas

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would "queue" up the items that need to be worked on. As users submit videos, you might do something like:

1. Move the uploaded file to somewhere it can be worked on
2. Create an entry in a system (in a MySQL database?) that keeps track of the videos that need to be processed.
3. A separate process ([cron-job](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-autotasks.html#s1-autotasks-cron)?) periodically looks at the queue, pops an item off the list, and executes the encoding command on a separate thread

FFMPEG probably has switches that can limit how much CPU it uses. For example, check this thread: [How can I limit FFMpeg CPU usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565567/how-can-i-limit-ffmpeg-cpu-usage)